# When specifying an empty export list can be useful?

Tags: haskell, module

It is possible to export no names of a module by specifying just a pair of parenthesis as the export list:

```
module MyModule () where
```

In which scenarios would this be useful? As far as I understand, any file importing `MyModule` won't be able to use any functions or types declared inside `MyModule`. At this point is seems like a useless feature of the langauge, but I suppose it is there for a reason.

Comment: Even if it were useless, complicating the grammar to disallow the empty case seems to have even less value. In fact, I believe typeclass instances will still be exported.

Comment: I just want to note that I'd generally advise against doing this because while it will export instances, they will be orphan instances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such a module will still export any class instances defined therein.

```
module A where

class Foo f where
  foo :: f

data Bar = Bar deriving (Show)
```

---

```
module B () where

import A

instance Foo Bar where
  foo = Bar
```

---

```
module C where

import A
import B -- won't compile without this import!

main = print (foo :: Bar)
```